# Car stalled. Brake pedal fully depressed and will not release, car engine will turn over but will not start

Tags: vw, golf, stall, cranks-wont-run

VW GOLF TSI (gasoline) 2015.

My car recently stopped working. It had been running for less than 5 minutes. I stopped at a stop sign and the brake felt a little stiff. I thought it had to do with the cold weather and the car not warming up yet. I went to accelerate and it felt very sluggish. The car jumped a bit. I pulled over and the car's engine was "shaking", I turned it off and popped the hood to see if I could see anything obvious. I tried starting it after that and it refused to start. I tried again a few minutes later and it gave me an error "Immobilization Active" or something to that effect. The brake pedal will not come back up and when I attempt to start the car the car simply turns over and nothing happens. Thinking it may be a battery issue I had a friend attempt to jump it to no avail. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the mileage on the vehicle? Your VW has a 3 yr/36,000 mi basic, 5 yr/60,000 mi powertrain warranty. If your mileage isn't excessive, take it to the dealership and have them fix it.

Comment: It sounds like something that has to do with the immobilizer. Did you try to read any codes?