# I have honda steed vlx 400cc

Tags: honda, motorcycle, steed

My original regulator burnt out, bought a new regulator rectifier and after one month my new regulator rectifier is also burnt out. 3rd I bought a new regulator rectifier and stay ok for 6 or 7 days and have since burnt out again.

How I can solve this problem?

Does the battery affect the regulator to die? My regulator is made in Taiwan, and there's no circuit short or leakage.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you please tell us exactly what your question is? Narrow it down for us?

Comment: my qs is why my new regulator I died again and again and its new regulator my stator is in good condition battery gives 12.25 or 26 and there is no short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, as well as the above, is the regulator properly earthed as if not it can cause damage.

Comment: Please don't use the answer area to post comments or ask clarifying questions.

Comment: @CharlieRB so, did you read the questions by Carguy....

Comment: I should have also commented the same to him. Sorry. Got side tracked.

Comment: BTW, what I tried to post or at least point out could, possibly, be the solution but it is very difficult to diagnose from the armchair so to speak - can be nearly as difficult as when you have the vehicle in front of you!!!

Comment: Can you flesh your answer out some by telling the OP *how* to diagnose a bad earth/ground? What does the OP need to do to fix it if this *is* the issue? These short answers are going to continue to get you zero sum votes as well as questions as to their validity in the comments.

Comment: Use a voltmeter to measure between a known good ground or earth point and the ground or earth terminal when the device should be functioning - result should be zero volts. Or, if you prefer, measure the resistance if it is not functioning and expect a result of zero ohms. If either shows a significant reading then clean and grease the ground or earth points.

Comment: Also, you will need a quality multimeter I have several : for accuracy Fluke or Avometer...

Comment: My questions were not of a clarifying nature, but of a troubleshooting procedure, which is why I answered my own comment.  Since @CharlieRB asked, the starter may be warm because it does not shut off completely after starting the engine -- a problem common to motorbikes -- and is therefore draining the battery, which in turn is causing the rectifier to work excessively.

Comment: @SolarMike - Yes, you are correct.  Look at the info page of Paulster2 and you will see that he has attended poor universities and has no real credentials in automotive repair.  He seems to be an amateur with no professional experience.  He is interested more in the process of answering a question, rather than the facts needed to resolve a problem.  It is not up to us to explain the basics.

Comment: In a post yesterday, I had my comments mysteriously erased from this website when I provided useful information.  It happened when I disagreed with an experienced poster, who was clearly not as informed as I was.  Have these people ever read George Orwell?

Comment: Personally attacking *Paulster2* by insulting where he was educated is not going to help anything.  You need to understand that sometimes people aren't going to agree with you. That does not mean you are free to attack them.  If you feel he is abusing you, feel free to report to the other [moderators](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) or contact @grace-note, who is the Stack Exchange community manager.

Answer (score 0):

How old is the battery?  If more than five years, replace it.  Feel the battery -- is it warm?  If yes, change the battery.

Does the starter motor get hot while the engine is running?  If so, it may be draining the battery and causing the rectifier to work too hard.

Also, the stator may be bad.  See [this link](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/21325/kawasaki-ex650-what-causes-a-stator-to-burn-out) for more information.

Comment: Please don't use the answer area for comments or ask clarifying questions. If the question is unclear, use the comment area below the question to get the additional information you need to answer the question.

Comment: @CharlieRB - If you notice, Carguy has attempted to answer his own clarifying comments. To Carguy, you may want to try and flesh your answers out some. *Why* would a hot starter indicate there's an issue? How would it be draining the battery and thus frying the rectifier? Give us more meat and you'll most likely be rewarded handsomely.

Comment: Paulster2 - You responded to a poster in exactly the same way I just did on Feb. 12 (http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/41904/car-stalled-brake-pedal-fully-depressed-and-will-not-release-car-engine-will-t).  Please don't reprimand me for something that you do yourself!  @CharlieRB - Just because you have many posts doesn't mean you can bully me!  I'm following the rules of this forum!

Comment: Sorry to have upset you. I'm not bullying anyone. When asking people to improve their posts, I could be a bit more encouraging.